# Increase numbers in col Y by 1 every time numbers in col X increases by 24

Tags: r, dataframe, seq

I want to increase my variables in column Y by 1 every time my column X increases by another 24. I have displayed the output I'm trying to create in column Y below.

```
x<-c(5,10,15,20,25,27,29,42,47,49,50,60)
y<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
```

Comment: If you assume you are starting count at 0 you can just do `df$y <- floor(df$x/24) + 1`

Comment: That's great thanks I wasn't aware of the floor func. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Another option is integer division `df$y <- df$x %/% 24 + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

```
floor(df$x/24) + 1
```